# Update hard drive firmware

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, firmware, xbox360

**Background:** I have a WD Scoprio Blue WD6400BPVT and am trying to run a firmware flashing tool to allow it to work as an internal Xbox 360 drive.  The device is able to be written over (a tool to write all 0's works), the device passes SMART status, chkdsk finds no errors, and if plugged into a windows device, it functions like a normal hard drive.

**The Problem:** When running the flashing tool, it warns about LGA size and errors out a few seconds later saying it can't read sector 16 and throws a drq error 0x0802.

**What I've tried:** I've tried various firmware files (bin) and all give the same error (none I can find have the same LGA size, not sure if that matters).  I've tried running tests on the drive and it appears to be healthy.  I've also tried different mobos in case it's a sata controller issue or something like that.  Looking up that error doesn't really tell me anything about what is actually going on so I'm kinda dead-ended there.

**Final Notes:** I've noticed that it makes an odd click sound every few minutes (like, maybe once every 5-10 min).  The click doesn't seem to change with use: doing a full write of 0's is the same as when the drive is doing nothing.  The power supply should be more than adequate for this setup so it shouldn't be an issue of insufficient power.

**The Question:** Is there hope?  Is there a tool to fix sector 16?  Would that even help?  Would matching the LGA sizes help this at all?  Or is the drive just dead and no amount of messing around will fix it?

After a full day of wrestling with MS-DOS 6.22 I'm rather frustrated!  Any thoughts would be appreciated!

**EDIT:** Yes, Xbox external drives are just a simple FAT32 format away from working like normal.  What I'm trying to do is get this set up to work as a first party internal drive, which means that I need to flash the firmware and put some special stuff in partition 2.  I have a tool to do this for me but I'm concerned about the drive I'm trying to use.

Comment: And what is “the flashing tool”? Where did you obtain firmware images? Are you sure they are compatible with your disk? You’ll brick the disk if they aren’t.

Comment: I have to ask.  Why do you believe you need to flash this firmware?  The Xbox 360 just uses a typical hdd with FAT32.  A HDD that makes a clicking sound should be replaced not used.

Comment: @DanielB - I'm using hddhackr, there are many tutorials out there for this specific tool.

Comment: @Ramhound - See the edit.  I'm trying to create and internal, not an external drive.  FAT32 formatting only works if you want to use a <=2TB drive through one of the USB2 slots.

Comment: Well, it seems your HDD is supported. I suggest you ask about your problem on their forums, it’s much more likely you’ll get expert support.